# Styling media queries not working on Chrome iPad

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, css, media-queries

So i have added some javascript to add a class to my body -

```
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(ipad)/);
if (agentID) {
    $("body").attr("id", "ipad");
    return;
}
```

I have three media queries one for standard mobile and one for retina, some of the mobile styling seems to be showing on chrome on iPad the media query is below

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}
```

And my third media query

```
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and     (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
```

But all the styles I put in either media query have no effect in Chrome on an ipad, it works perfectly on Safari on an iPad. Even the javascript which adding the class doesn't seem to be working, i've added

```
#ipad body {background-color:red!important;}
```

to the main css outside the media queries and nothing.

It's just chrome that isn't behaving. I have cleared the cache and browser data but still nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a viewport meta tag? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">`

Comment: @Mooseman yes i am using that meta tag but still nothing